# MYSQL COUNT with SELECT condition

Tags: mysql

Im newbie please help me on my project. I have 2 tables below.

Table user:

[image: Table User]

Table Likes

[image: Table Likes]

I want to count all likes per story_id and check if the given user has like the story else it will return null.

as of now this is my query and output, given user id = 1.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) , sl.story_id, u.id as user
FROM stories_likes sl
LEFT JOIN users u ON sl.user_id = u.id AND sl.user_id = 1
GROUP BY sl.story_id
```

My output: 
[image: OUTPUT]

But what i want to get output is: 
Given: user_id = 1

[image]

Given user_id = 4

[image]

Sorry for the construction of my question i dont know how. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the query should display the result for a one particular `user_id` only then try the following query:

```
select count(*),
       story_id,
       (case find_in_set(1, Group_concat(user_id separator ',')) >0 then 1
             else NULL
        end
       )as user_id
from Stories_Likes
group by story_id;
```

In above query, you can put user_id manually after `when`, or you can set a variable with particular Id and use it in the query.

For i.e., if you want to check for `user_id=4`, then put `4` after `when` and `then`.

[Click here for the Updated Demo](http://rextester.com/HNY38036)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi. thanks for replying. btw still didnt get the exact output. in your example demo. user_id = 1 has liked the story_id 1 and 4. but the output of your query show null on story_id = 1. it should be the user_id because the user_id 1 both like story_id.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I've edited the answer as well as link of the demo. Please try it out.

Comment: Thank you, I already got the answer. but anyway i appreciate your effort so I mark your answer as the answer to this question. Thanks !

Comment: @Eyy Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The `users` table is left joined to the query, so it may have `null` values. Instead, you should use the `user_id` column from the `stories_likes` table:

```
SELECT    COUNT(*) , sl.story_id, sl.user_id as user
-- Here --------------------------^
FROM      stories_likes sl
LEFT JOIN users u ON sl.user_id = u.id AND sl.user_id = 1
GROUP BY  sl.story_id
```

Comment: But wait! hey. did you try the given user_id = 4? it didnt get the expected output. help

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer. for those who has the same problem and needed this here's the answer.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) , sl.story_id, t.user_id
FROM stories_likes sl
LEFT JOIN users u ON sl.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM stories_likes WHERE user_id = 4) t ON 
sl.story_id = t.story_id
GROUP BY  sl.story_id
```

Where the given user is declared on temporary table `t`

Comment: If you are not displaying any info of user from `users` table, then there is no need to join the table. You already have `user_id` in `stories_likes` table.